# Python Heapify vs Sort

Tags: python, sorting, heap

Is there an advantage to using heapfiy vs sort?  Sometimes I see people use heapify and then other codes I see use sort.

Are they both NLOGN?

Comment: "Algorithmically, they are both O(NLOGN)." - wrong. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: These are two entirely different operations. It's not a matter of advantages and disadvantages; you use the operation you need.

Comment: how do you know when you should use one vs the other. many times when i use heapify, i can use replace it with sort and it works still

Comment: It depends on the problem that needs to be solved. If for instance you actually only need a part of the input to be sorted (on average), then a heap might be the better choice. If one sort operation is not enough to solve the problem (because the array undergoes some changes, additions, removals), then again a heap might be the better option. If however the use of the heap just turns into an alternative for slow sorting, then you better sort.